# Committing existing project to git and github

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-commit, git-push

I have a fairly large android studio project and I now want to commit the entire project to git and then to github but I'm stuck! I know how to add a file to the staging area and committing it or committing all modified files but ***how do I commit an entire project to git instead of committing files singly?***

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create your repository on github
2. Init (locally) your repository by typing in your terminal `git init` (you should change your working directory to project main folder)
3. Perform a `git add .`
4. Perform your first commit `git commit -m "First project commit"`
5. Tell git where your remote repository is and what's the source name `git remote add origin <remote repository url provided by github>`
6. Push your branch on remote `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Just one more question, if I later change one file, should I add that file alone to the staging area and commit or should I commit the entire directory again?

Comment: @MananMehta you simply cannot add files to stage (and so you cannot commit and pushing) if they are not changed anyhow. So, as long as you are adding files to stage are with `git add .` or `git add *`, you will only add changed files. Of course you can also add singular files or a subset of modified ones: just specify their path instead of `.` or `*` to `git add`

Comment: OH! Got it! Thank you, again! You're the best!